# How to replace a string with parts of it between markers (regex)?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text, let's say:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit [[amet]], consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod [[time (sample)|tempor]]  incididunt ut [[labore]] et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I want to replace the `[[time (sample)|tempor]]` with `tempor`.
The structure is always the same: `[[string to remove|string to extract]]` and can appear several times in the text.

I tried regular expressions in regex, but I wasn't successful without cutting off half of the text: `re.sub(r'\[.*?\|', '', text)`

How can I replace the string?

Comment: What result do you want to get? `[[time (sample)|tempor]]` must be `[[tempor]]`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want `[[tempor]]` from `[[time (sample)|tempor]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex to collect only the relevant field

```py
r'\[\[[\w\s\(\)]+?\|(.+?)\]\]'
```

```py
import re
regex = r'\[\[[\w\s\(\)]+?\|(.+?)\]\]'

text = '''
Lorem ipsum dolor sit [[amet]], consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod [[time (sample)|tempor]]  incididunt ut [[labore]] et dolore magna aliqua.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit [[amet]], consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod [[time (sample)|tempor]]  incididunt ut [[labore]] et dolore magna aliqua.
'''

txt = re.sub(regex, '[[\g<1>]]', text)
print(txt)
```

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit [[amet]], consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod [[tempor]]  incididunt ut [[labore]] et dolore magna aliqua.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit [[amet]], consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod [[tempor]]  incididunt ut [[labore]] et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Regex101 sample [here](https://regex101.com/r/s8dfY2/1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works for the sample text! I also have text which does not split over multiple lines. If I run your regex code with the sample text above - without separated lines - it cuts off the input text. The output is: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit [[tempor]]  incididunt ut [[labore]] et dolore magna aliqua.` Is there also a regex which takes this into account?

Comment: @jonas I've edit the answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you. I hope it'll help some other people too.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
\[\[(?:(?!\[\[)[^|])*\|(.*?)]]
```

Replace with `[[\1]]` or `\1`, depending on the requirements.

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/r3aPjT/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^|]                     any character except: '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]]                       ']]'
```